# How many group homomorphisms are there from $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$ to $(\mathbb{Z}_4, +_4)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

I think there is only one $f(x)= x$ mod $4$.

Comment: You've got another think coming.

Comment: There is **always** the trivial group homomorphism that maps everything to the group identity element.

Comment: There are four of them: $f(x)=x \pmod 4$ or $f(x)=2x \pmod 4$, or $f(x)=3x \pmod 4$ or $f(x)=0 \pmod 4$

Comment: Such a homomorphism is determined by $f(1)$. (Why?)